# Printing a python dict without the unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I have a dictionary of strings I need to print to my terminal for debugging a regex. It's printing as character code spew instead of something readable:

```
{'\x00F\x00a\x00c\x00e\x00b\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00 \x00/\x00 \x00T\x00w\x00i\x00t\x00t\x00e\x00r\x00':
 '\x00F\x00a\x00c\x00e\x00b\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00 \x00/\x00 \x00T\x00w\x00i\x00t\x00t\x00e\x00r\x00'}
```

How can print the dict as something readable?

Comment: Decode your byte strings. That looks like utf16 to me.

Comment: I'm Not a python guy. Is that some kind of environment setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {'\x00F\x00a\x00c\x00e\x00b\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00 \x00/\x00 \x00T\x00w\x00i\x00t\x00t\x00e\x00r\x00':
 '\x00F\x00a\x00c\x00e\x00b\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00 \x00/\x00 \x00T\x00w\x00i\x00t\x00t\x00e\x00r\x00'}

for key, value in d.items():
    print (key+" : "+value).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This does not seem like UTF-8 to me.